# How to create a query that searches different tables on the same database to log a user into a website?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I'm building a simple login/registration feature, and I'm having a little trouble.

The issue is this, the user system I'm designing is supposed to accommodate different types of users, like (Blue users, Red users, Black users etc). So I was considering porting their different user data to separate database tables, and even giving them separate registration pages, because the content they would view on the site would vary depending on their color.

For example:

Blue Users:

```
INSERT 'username' INTO `blue` where...
```

Red Users:

```
INSERT 'username' INTO `red` where...
```

But I want to know if there's a way to log them into the site from the same login page without resorting to sending them to different pages when they want to login. I tried the following:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `blue`,`red`  WHERE `username`...
```

but it did not work, so I'm asking if there's a way to register the different user types on the same page and log them in on the same page while still giving them their different content.

Comment: So, are you saying for each user, you will create separate table. But why ?

Comment: Use join to get data from two talbes

Comment: Not for each use, but for each type of users. It makes sense if you e.g. have students and teachers

Comment: @SourceOverflow even for each type of user. I don't think so. We can simply have a column

Comment: You can use UNION  `SELECT id FROM blue WHERE... UNION ALL SELECT id FROM red WHERE...`

Comment: Have a central table for all users, and then specialised tables for different colours. Usernames, passwords, etc all go in the central table. You can then have a 1:1 relation between the central table and each specialisation table. The centralised table should contain a reference to which colour a user is, so your logic can select from the correct sub-table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is probably that the "id" value is an auto-incremented primary key, right? Therefore it would be unique to only the table that they are in, but not over all tables (blue, red, black)

You would then always have to make sure to have unique usernames and ids over all groups or let them select what group they are when they log in and then only load data from that table.

If you have already solved the uniqueness problem, you should be able to simply use the union querys already suggested by other users. You can't use `blue, red`, because that is short for `blue JOIN red`, which of course will only result in data where columns with the same name are equal across blue and red.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user can be just in one table, you could use UNION...

```
SELECT id FROM blue WHERE username...
UNION
SELECT id FROM red WHERE username...
```

... but as a piece of advice, if user info is the same for all, you better have one table for usertypes and another for users, and link them with a foreign key...

```
USERTYPES TABLE
id_usertype
usrt_name

USERS TABLE
id_user
id_usertype (this should be a foreign key)
usrname
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: That sounds like it would over-complicate things that are common to all users, such as user names, passwords, personal data, user category etc.

Comment: @halfer I know! I was editing the question to explain it, but you went too fast for me!! XD